# Cannot import QtCore or QtGui from PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, windows-7-x64

I have found plenty of posts regarding this issue, but no answers that work for me.

**PROBLEM:**
I am trying to run this code:
    `from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui`
I get this error in return:
    `ImportError: cannot import name QtCore`
I append the path to PyQt4 to sys.path (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4) and importing just PyQt4 throws no errors. I can see that QtCore.pyd and QtGui.pyd are in that directory and the directory has its `__init__.py` file.

**Specs:**
Windows 7 x64
python v2.6.8
PyQt v4.10.4

Comment: `C:\Python27` and `python v2.6.8` - that doesn't seem right. Are you trying to use PyQt4 from a newer python installation in an older version? That won't work.

Comment: Right, the version of python I am using is 2.6.8. There are only two versions of PyQt available on the riverbank computing website, for python 3.3 and python 2.7. Hence why I had to add the path to sys.path. I presumed that the 2.7 version would work with 2.x but I suppose I am mistaken? If so, is there a version of PyQt that works with 2.6.8 somewhere?

Comment: It's open source, you can compile it yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python-2.6.x, you will have to use an installer for an earlier version of PyQt4. The most recent version available is for PyQt-4.10/Qt-4.8.4, which can be downloaded from here:

- [PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py2.6-Qt4.8.4-x64.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10/PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py2.6-Qt4.8.4-x64.exe/download)
- [PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py2.6-Qt4.8.4-x32.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10/PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py2.6-Qt4.8.4-x32.exe/download)