# Python 3 : ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'

Tags: python, pyside

I am using python 3.4.2 with PySide and when i run below program i am getting ImportError.

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
import sys, time

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Below is my Path variable..

```
'/home/naresh/Python_Practice/PySide_Qt_Practice', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/home/naresh/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

help me to solve this issue.....I am new to python..

Comment: Paths to python libs go to PYTHONPATH env variable, not Path.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround. This worked:

```
# Various imports, whatever, using normal sys.path, for example:
import os, sys, re, time, random
import subprocess, psutil

# Save sys.path
sys_path_saved = sys.path

# Limit sys.path for PySide import
sys.path = ['c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']

# PySide imports with limited sys.path
from PySide        import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.QtGui  import QApplication, QLineEdit
from PySide.QtCore import QSettings, Qt

# Reset sys.path to original
sys.path = sys_path_saved
```

Pyinstaller 1.5.1 should do a fine job of locating dependencies, and often does. However, all of many many attempts to use its pathex or hiddenimports in .spec failed. Modifying my environment variables also failed. Extracting various module files manually from from .egg sometimes worked.

However for PySide imports, the sys.path temporary limitation above was the workaround that worked.

Update: Unfortunately the exe only works on a machine with Python/Pyside installed, doesn't work on XP without Python.

Got this from here : [Cannot import QtCore or QtGui from PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622292/cannot-import-qtcore-or-qtgui-from-pyqt4)